# Rails complex routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I need to make some complex routing in rails application: e.g. something like

```
match '/:ObjectName/:Method' => ???
```

so that depending on the properties of the Object I need to call different controller and action. Is it possible?

The final goal here is to make some kind of object-oriented actions, so that I could make multiple controllers derived from one-another which would add/rewrite actions from parent controllers. Depending on the properties of the particular object in DB, I would relate it to this or that controller.

If it is not possible to achieve with `routes.rb` I can make some kind of routing myself inside the controller, so I would have to use `redirect_to`, but how can I specify there all params that were passed with original request?

**UPDATE**

Here is another example:

I have a model `SpaceShipTypes`. It has some fields, say `:type_name`, `:weapon_type`, `:shield_type`, `:cargo_type`. There is a `SpaceShipTypesController` with actions like `create`, `update` so that I could manage types using some kind of API.

There is also another model - `SpaceShips`. It does have fields too, like `:name`, `:type_id`, `:position`. There is even a `SpaceShipsController` with actions like `create`, `destroy`, `move`.

Now here is the thing - for **some** of space ship types I want to change the behavior of standard controller actions and/or write additional actions. So that when I make a call `/ship1/move` I need to dynamically check `:type_id` of the particular space ship and get the right action.

So I figured, it would be nice to make derived controller like

```
class BattleStationsController < SpaceShipController
  def move
  # does nothing
  end
end

class DeathStarsController < SpaceShipsController
  def overkill
    SpaceShip.find(params[:target_id]).destroy
  end
end

...
```

I wish I could do this nicely with the help of routes.rb, but don't see a clue... So maybe I need to write a special controller to handle additional routing:

```
class RoutingsController < ApplicationController
  def route
    ship = SpaceShip.find(params[:name])
    case (ship.type_id)
      when 'battlestation' then redirect_to :controller => 'battlestations', ...
      when 'deathstar' then redirect_to :controller => 'deathstars', ...
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

But I don't know how to redirect all initially passed params so that I don't have to write a ton of

```
redirect_to :controller => '...', :action => '...', :param1 => params[:param1], param2 => params[:param2], ...
```

Comment: object-oriented actions? I believe you are on your way to duplicating what rails already does for you. Take a look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @sytycs, I've looked there but still have no clue. Let's take an example:
I have a model called Points with three fields: name (string), type(string) and position(integer). And two actions: changetype and move.
Now if type = "blue", move would add 1 to position, if type = "red" it would subtract 1.
What I want to achieve is - when I call /point1/move I get a correct change in position of point1 no matter of the type, I don't specify the type in URL and the type may change with time.
Real logic is of course much more complicated and I may need to render different views for different object, etc

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm getting what you want to achieve.

From your comment I understand you actually just wish to increment/decrement a points position without caring about its type. I'm not sure but I think you cannot update the attribute of an element without knowing its type, because how could you get that object from the database?

But it seems like you're passing the objects type in the url anyway (your comment: `/point1/move`) :

So you could do something like:

`match => '/:object_type' => 'positionscontroller#move'`

create a `PositionsController` which has:

```
def move
  if params[:object_type] == "point" # or whatever else you might have
   object = Points.find(params[:points_id])
  end

  if object.type == "blue"
    object.update_attr(:position, ...)
  else # object.type == "red"
    object.update_attr(:position, ...)
  end
end
```

Note this code is not beautiful, but I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Hi, that's not exactly what I want, please see update to the original post.